# Show there are no integer solutions to $x^4+x^2=y^4-5$

Tags: number-theory

How can I show that there are no integer solutions to the equation $x^4+x^2=y^4-5$?

I've tried considering the units digit and also factorising differently but can't seem to reach a contradiction.

EDIT: $x^4+x^2=y^4+5$

Comment: As a rule, it's bad practice to substantially modify a problem once you have received answers.  It can make the received answers irrelevant and confusing.  In this case, as it happens, the same techniques that work for the pre-edit version work for the post-edit version so the damage is limited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite to obtain $$x^2+5=y^4-x^4=(y-x)(y+x)(y^2+x^2)$$

It follows that $x^2+y^2$ is a divisor of $x^2+5$.  Since they can not be equal, we must then have $$x^2+y^2≤\frac {x^2+5}2\implies x^2≤5-2y^2$$

Since $x^2≥0$ we see that we have very few cases to check.

Note:  the solution above referred to the pre-edited version of the equation.  The same method works, even more simply,  for the post-edit version since you wind up with $x^2≤-5-2y^2$.

Answer (score 1):

$(2x^2+1)^2-(2y^2)^2=21$. Now just factorise,  and break into cases.  Or you can sandwich between two consecutive  perfect squares like this : 
$(x^2)^2<x^4+x^2-5<(x^2+1)^2$.,  so the given expression can't be a perfect square,  so forget about perfect fourth power.

Comment: Given the edit above I've replaced the $-19$ by $21$

Comment: In that case use can use the sandwich approach.

Answer (score 0):

$x^4+x^2=y^4+5$ has no solution mod $8$.

$x^4+x^2=y^4-5$ has no solution mod $13$.

Comment: @Loobear23, I just wrote a simple program to test all possible pairs for small moduli.

Comment: @Loobear23, I can but I suggest you try.