# Show there are no non-trivial integer solutions to $a^2+3b^2=2c^2$

Tags: number-theory

How can I show there are no non-trivial integer solutions to $a^2+3b^2=2c^2$?

I have tried to play with the equation and different moduli but still no success, can’t find a solution anywhere online.

Comment: cf. [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1085454p4795221)

Comment: How did you find so easily?

Comment: using https://approach0.xyz/search/; cf. [here](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24x%5E2%2B3y%5E2%3D2z%5E2%24&p=1$)

Comment: What have you tried?  Like [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3525730/show-there-are-no-integer-solutions-to-x4x2-y4-5) this one shows no sign of any effort at all.

Comment: Thanks for the help @J.W.Tanner

Comment: Well, talk about the random things you tried?  What happen $\mod 2$?  What happened $\mod 4$?  What happened $\mod 3$?

Answer (score 2):

If $a$ is odd, then $b$ must be odd, and modulo $8$, we have
$2c^2\equiv 4\pmod 8$, i.e., $c^2\equiv 2\pmod 4$, which is absurd.
Hence $a$ must be even. Then $b$ must be even as well and the left hand side is a multiple of $4$. Then $c$ must also be even, and we can reduce to a smaller solution $a/2,b/2,c/2$ (unless $a=b0c=0$ to begin with).

Answer (score 1):

Please verify the lemma that $ 3|a^2+b^2\implies 3|a, 3|b$.
Now transform the equation like this : with $(a, b, c)=1$.

$3a^2+3b^2=2(c^2+a^2)\implies 3|c^2+a^2\implies 3|c, 3|a$ but this would mean $3|b$,  (because that would mean $9x^2+3b^2=18y^2\implies 9|3b^2\implies 3|b$)  this is a contradiction since,  $(a, b, c)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Hagen von Eitzens $\mod 2^k$ answer is this $\mod 3$ answer.

If there is a non-trivial solution then

$a^2 \equiv -c^2 \pmod 3$ but $1^2,(-1)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ so the only way that is possible is if $a \equiv c \equiv 0\pmod 3$.

But if $a = 3a'$ and $c = 3c'$ then we have $b^2 = 3(2c'^2 - a'^2)$ and $3|b$ and so if we replace $b= 3b'$ we get $a'^2 + 3b'^2 = 2c'^2$ and to solve that we get an infinite regress.

====

Addendum:  If you have non-trivial (at least one of $a,b,c$ is non-zero) solution $a^2 + 3b^2 = 2c^2$ then $(\frac {a}{\gcd(a,b,c)})^2 + 3(\frac {b}{\gcd(a,b,c)})^2 = 2(\frac c{\gcd(a,b,c)})^2$ so we can assume without loss of generality that we want to solve with a common divisor between $a,b$ and $c$.

When I showed that all $a,b,c$ must be divisible by $3$ or when Hagen von Eitzen showed that all $a,b,c$ must be divisible by $2$ (or both of us together showed all $a,b,c$ must be divisible by $6$) we have an irresolvable infinite regress.

....

It makes me curious, for gits and shizzles, if a $\mod 5$ argument is viable.

$a^2 \equiv 2(b^2 + c^2)\pmod 5$.  $k^2 \equiv 0,1$, so $b^2 + c^2 \equiv 0,1,2$ and $2(b^2+c^2)\equiv 0,2,-1$.  So $a^2 \equiv 2(b^2+c^2)\implies a,b,c \equiv 0\pmod 5$.

So .... that's impossible.

$\mod 7$, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

$$ a^2+3b^2=2c^2 $$

---

$$
 a^2+c^2=3(c^2-b^2)\qquad \qquad \phantom {\text{dsf  dsfsd}}\\
 \implies \qquad \qquad \phantom {\text{dsf  dsfsd}}\\
 a^2+c^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3\\
 \implies \qquad \qquad \phantom {\text{dsf  dsfsd}}\\
 a \equiv c \equiv 0 \pmod 3\\
 \implies \qquad \qquad \phantom {\text{dsf  dsfsd}}\\
 a = 3a_1 \qquad , c=3c_1 \\
 \implies \qquad \qquad \phantom {\text{dsf  dsfsd}}\\
 9(a_1^2+c_1^2)=3(c^2-b^2)\\
 3(a_1^2+c_1^2)=(9c_1^2-b^2)\\
 \implies \qquad \qquad \phantom {\text{dsf  dsfsd}}\\
 b \equiv 0 \pmod 3\\
 \implies \qquad \qquad \phantom {\text{dsf  dsfsd}}\\
 b = 3b_1 \qquad \qquad \quad\\
 \implies \qquad \qquad \phantom {\text{dsf  dsfsd}}\\
 3(a_1^2+c_1^2)=9(c_1^2-b_1^2)$$

---

$$
 a_1^2+c_1^2=3(c_1^2-b_1^2) \qquad \qquad \phantom {\text{dsf  dsfsd}}\\
 \cdots \qquad \text{ infinite descent!}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Obviously we can assume that $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$. So modulo $3$, $a^2\equiv -c^2$ implies $3\mid a,c$ and hence $3\nmid b$, but this is a contradiction mod $9$.